# spring boot specific profile yaml not loading

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, yaml

I have a yaml file as follows:-

```
spring:
  profiles: test
msg: test
---
spring:
  profiles : dev
msg: hello
---
spring:
  profiles : prod
msg: production
```

located in `/src/main/java/resources` as `application.yaml`

my code the read the values from this file is as follows

```
@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties
public class TestConfig {

    private String msg;

    public String getMsg() {
        return msg;
    }

    public void setMsg(String msg) {
        this.msg = msg;
    }
}
```

I create a bean of this class as following:-

```
@Bean
public TestConfig testConfig() {
    return new TestConfig();
}
```

But trying to see the profile specific information does not work with the following code:-

```
public class Main implements CommandLineRunner{

    @Autowired
    private TestConfig testConfig;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SpringApplication.run(Main.class, args);

    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("it works!!!");
        System.out.println(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>   " + testConfig.getMsg());
    }
}
```

Any help here is much appreciated.

Thanks,
Amar

Comment: If you are using Maven\Gradle it should be in `src\main\resources\config` folder also the file extension should be `.yml`

Comment: I added the file as you mentioned, changed the extension, ran it using  ./gradlew -Dspring.profiles.active=dev clean bootrun. But it prints null

Answer (score 2):

I solved my issue,
I had a custom bootrun in my build script, which was overriding my spring.profiles.active system property to some value.
I made a few tweaks here and there and now its working fine.
Thanks for everyone's time!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Your yaml file should start with three dashes `---` and be named ".yml".
Make sure to position it in `/src/main/resources/`, your current location would place it under a `resources` directory in the output, which is not what you want.

Comment: I tried this as well. but  null gets printed in the console

Comment: If you launch without specifying a profile, no value will be present, since you only specify a value for the profiles 'test', 'prod', 'dev'
You can either specify a default value or set a default profile to fix this.

Comment: I plan to use different properties for different environments i.e different values for dev, prod and test environments. When my application starts up, these values are to be read automatically.